# Regular Expression for multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have made this regular expression `((\s\s\s.*\s)*)` . It means , 3 spaces or tabs , after that a number of characters and a space or a tab or an end of line. 
How can I store to a list each line I get?

So , if I have something like this :

```
___The rabbit caught the lion\n
___The tiger got the giraffe\n
___The owl hit the man\n
```

the output to be like this :

```
list=[The rabbit caught the lion, The tiger got the giraffe, The owl hit the man]
```

Just to mention that I use groups for each of the other patterns that I have.

Comment: Have you ever heard about `str.splitlines`?

Comment: Does the regex's group return a string ?

Comment: `re.findall('\s{3}(.*)', text)`

Comment: @JBernardo That expression should at least be anchored to the start of the line.

Comment: @Jack Yeah, but if all the lines got the 3 spaces, you don't need to. The `$` is surely not needed (unless you use DOTALL)

Comment: @JBernardo That's not a given; without the anchor it would match `"Bla...Something else"` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to match a whole line, starting with three spaces (or tabs); this can be done with `re.MULTILINE` and using the `^` and `$` anchors.

```
matches = re.findall('^\s{3}(.*)$', contents, re.MULTILINE)
```

If you don't care about having characters before the three spaces,you can reduce the expression to this:

```
matches = re.findall('\s{3}(.*)', contents)
```

This is because `.` will match everything up to a newline (by default).